# Dir only returns 1 file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to get a simple list of files using the dir function and the result only returns 1 file even though there are 200 of them.  Any ideas what i might be missing in the following function?

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub getList()
Const strFolder As String = "c:\Users\bob\Desktop\social\"
Dim strFile As String
'strFile = Dir(strFolder & strPattern, vbNormal)
strFile = Dir(strFolder, vbNormal)
Debug.Print strFile
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Debug.Print strFile
    strFile = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This code works just fine for me. Are you executing it directly in the VBA IDE, or are you triggering it with a macro? Do you have any funky file names in that folder that might be breaking the output window? I'm just spitballing here.

Comment: I'm just copying and pasting the above into a module and executing it from an immediate window.  I just checked the file names and some have an ampersand.  I guess that is breaking the code?

Answer (score 0):

ampersands display OK for me. maybe there is a different character causing problems though. try replacing this line

```
strFile = Dir(strFolder, vbNormal)
```

with this,

```
strFile = Replace(Dir(strFolder, vbNormal), "&", Chr(37))
```

then change the & and Chr(37) to replace other strange characters with their chr equivalents so then maybe you can identify the issue.